# Google analytics objects in SWIFT classes that have test target membership gives compile error

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift, google-analytics, xcode6

I've been successfully using Google Analytics for iOS for a while in some other applications using SWIFT.  However, I've run across a specific scenario that I cannot seem to solve.

I have an AnalyticsHelper class that has a simple method that sends an event to Google through my default tracker.  When I try to create an instance of this AnalyticsHelper class in any other class in my project that has target membership in my test target, it doesn't recognize the AnalyticsHelper object and gives a compile error.  However, creating an instance of this AnalyticsHelper class in any other class that does NOT have target membership in my test target works just fine.

If I try to add my AnalyticsHelper class to my test target, I get a compile error in my AnalyticsHelper class because it can't identify any of the Google Analytics objects (Use of unresolved identifier 'xxx').  Seems like it may be some type of linker error, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any idea how to solve this issue?  I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2008a), Google Analytics 3.09.

AnalyticsHelper class:

```
import Foundation

public class AnalyticsHelper {

func logBarcodeScan() {
    let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "Scanning")
    tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("UX", action: "scanBarcode",
        label: "bagTag", value: nil).build() as NSDictionary)
    tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: nil)
    }
}
```

Class that doesn't have target membership in my test target, creates instance of AnalyticsHelper without any problem:

```
import UIKit

class StartViewController: UIViewController {

let analyticsHelper = AnalyticsHelper()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Class that does have target membership in my test target, gives an unresolved identifier 'AnalyticsHelper' error on compile:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ScanViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
let analyticsHelper = AnalyticsHelper()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally discovered the answer.

1) In the Test Target Build Settings, set the Objective-C Bridging Header file setting to the same file your App target uses for this setting.

2) In the Test Target Build Phases, add the libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a to the Link Binary With Libraries section, along with the other 3 frameworks that Google Analytics requires (CoreData, SystemConfiguration, libz.dylib).

After these steps, everything worked for me.